# Error on using aws change-resource-record-sets to add an alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to use aws change-resource-record-sets to add an alias. The idea is to allow access to a Cloudfront distribution via URL on our domain (e.g. mydomainname.mycompany.co.uk rather than mydomainname.cloudfront.net where mydomainname=something like *d4dzc6m38sq0mk*)

After working through various other JSON errors, which I solved, I am still getting a problem.

```
A client error (InvalidChangeBatch) occurred: RRSet with DNS name 
mydomainname.cloudfront.net. is not permitted in zone mycompany.co.uk.
```

What have I got wrong?

JSON:

```
{
  "Comment": "Recordset for mydomainname",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "mydomainname",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2",
          "DNSName": "mydomainname.cloudfront.net.",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDITED to clarify the HostedZoneID.

Comment: Have you also declared mydomainname.mycompany.co.uk as an alias for your distribution inside cloudfront? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: Yes. And I can see it set there on the Distribution when I look via the web interface. Do you need to do this before or after creating the recordset? For some reason I was not sure (think I have tried both ways).

Comment: It would stand to reason that cloudfront needs to be configured first, Route 53 later, if there's any cross-validation going on.  I would suggest that "Name": "mydomainname" should be specified as "Name": "mydomainname.mycompany.co.uk", since from what I've read, the console sometimes does implicit adding of the rest of the domain name while the API doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass complete name in the `NAME` parameter. for your example you need to pass this:

```
"Name" : "mydomainname.cloudfront.net."
```

Answer (score 2):

If "The idea is to allow access to a Cloudfront distribution via URL on our domain..." then try a CNAME instead of an alias...

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z3A********TC8 --change-batch file://~/tmp/awsroute53recordset.json
```

awsroute53recordset.json

```
{
  "Comment": "Allow access to a Cloudfront distribution via URL on our domain",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "cdn.mycompany.co.uk",
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "TTL": 3600,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "d4dzc6m38sq0mk.cloudfront.net"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the 'Change' => node.

```
            'Comment' => 'Created Programmatically',
            'Changes' => [
                'Change'=>[
                    'Action' => 'CREATE',
                    'ResourceRecordSet' => [
                        'Name' => $domainName.'.',
                        'Type' => 'A',
                        'AliasTarget' => [
                            'HostedZoneId' => '*ZoneID*',
                            'DNSName' => '*DNSName*',
                            'EvaluateTargetHealth' => false
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
```